# forward http request to pod running on worker node

Tags: kubernetes

Context:
I am trying to setup a kubernetes cluster on my PC using virtual box.
Here's the setup -
In this setup i am able to launch pods from the control plane, as well as able to send http requests to pods
[image]

here CP01: master/control plane, W01  - worker1, W02 - worker2 node.

I had initialized control plane using  -

```
master] kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address 10.5.5.1 --pod-network-cidr 10.244.0.0/16 --cri-socket unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock
worker] kubeadm join 10.5.5.1:6443  --token jv5pxe.t07snw8ewrbejn6i   --cri-socket  unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock      --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:10fc6e3fdc2085085f1ea1a75c9eb4316f13759b0d3773377db86baa30d8b972
```

I am able to create deployment as -

### run.yaml

```yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Here's the load balancer -

### serv.yaml

```yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

and from the cp01 node , i am able to hit both the pods via load balancer

```
[root@cp01 ~]# kubectl get services
NAME          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
hello-world   LoadBalancer   10.96.81.128   <pending>     80:31785/TCP   3m56s
[root@cp01 ~]# curl 10.96.81.128|grep Welcome
   <title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
   <h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
```

I have following 2 Queries -

Q1: What settings to i need to carry out to make the flannel work without enp0s3 interface?
I don't need external connectivity on w01 and w02. So if i disable the enp0s3 on w01 and w02, the flannel pods on worker starts failing. Here's is how i tried reproducing issue on w01 -

```
[root@cp01 ~]# kubectl get pods -A
NAMESPACE      NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-mp8zs          1/1     Running   8 (31m ago)     41m
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-p5kwj          1/1     Running   2 (12h ago)     3d1h
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-wqpwl          1/1     Running   0               24m
kube-system    coredns-565d847f94-xddkq       1/1     Running   1 (12h ago)     15h
kube-system    coredns-565d847f94-xl7pj       1/1     Running   1 (12h ago)     15h
kube-system    etcd-cp01                      1/1     Running   2 (12h ago)     3d1h
kube-system    kube-apiserver-cp01            1/1     Running   2 (12h ago)     3d1h
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-cp01   1/1     Running   2 (12h ago)     3d1h
kube-system    kube-proxy-9f4xm               1/1     Running   2 (12h ago)     3d1h
kube-system    kube-proxy-dhhqc               1/1     Running   2 (12h ago)     3d1h
kube-system    kube-proxy-w64gc               1/1     Running   1 (2d16h ago)   3d1h
kube-system    kube-scheduler-cp01            1/1     Running   2 (12h ago)     3d1h
[root@cp01 ~]# ssh w01 'nmcli con down enp0s3'
[root@cp01 ~]# kubectl delete pod -n kube-flannel kube-flannel-ds-mp8zs
pod "kube-flannel-ds-mp8zs" deleted
[root@cp01 ~]# kubectl delete pod -n kube-flannel kube-flannel-ds-wqpwl
pod "kube-flannel-ds-wqpwl" deleted
[root@cp01 ~]# kubectl get pods -A
NAMESPACE      NAME                           READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-2kqq5          0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   2 (25s ago)     45s
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-kcwk6          1/1     Running            0               49s
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-p5kwj          1/1     Running            2 (12h ago)     3d1h
kube-system    coredns-565d847f94-xddkq       1/1     Running            1 (12h ago)     15h
kube-system    coredns-565d847f94-xl7pj       1/1     Running            1 (12h ago)     15h
kube-system    etcd-cp01                      1/1     Running            2 (12h ago)     3d1h
kube-system    kube-apiserver-cp01            1/1     Running            2 (12h ago)     3d1h
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-cp01   1/1     Running            2 (12h ago)     3d1h
kube-system    kube-proxy-9f4xm               1/1     Running            2 (12h ago)     3d1h
kube-system    kube-proxy-dhhqc               1/1     Running            2 (12h ago)     3d1h
kube-system    kube-proxy-w64gc               1/1     Running            1 (2d16h ago)   3d1h
kube-system    kube-scheduler-cp01            1/1     Running            2 (12h ago)     3d1h
```

here's the reason -

```
[root@cp01 ~]# kubectl logs -n kube-flannel kube-flannel-ds-2kqq5
Defaulted container "kube-flannel" out of: kube-flannel, install-cni-plugin (init), install-cni (init)
I1005 08:17:59.211331       1 main.go:207] CLI flags config: {etcdEndpoints:http://127.0.0.1:4001,http://127.0.0.1:2379 etcdPrefix:/coreos.com/network etcdKeyfile: etcdCertfile: etcdCAFile: etcdUsername: etcdPassword: version:false kubeSubnetMgr:true kubeApiUrl: kubeAnnotationPrefix:flannel.alpha.coreos.com kubeConfigFile: iface:[] ifaceRegex:[] ipMasq:true ifaceCanReach: subnetFile:/run/flannel/subnet.env publicIP: publicIPv6: subnetLeaseRenewMargin:60 healthzIP:0.0.0.0 healthzPort:0 iptablesResyncSeconds:5 iptablesForwardRules:true netConfPath:/etc/kube-flannel/net-conf.json setNodeNetworkUnavailable:true}
W1005 08:17:59.211537       1 client_config.go:614] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
E1005 08:17:59.213916       1 main.go:224] Failed to create SubnetManager: error retrieving pod spec for 'kube-flannel/kube-flannel-ds-2kqq5': Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-flannel/pods/kube-flannel-ds-2kqq5": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: network is unreachable
```

Q2: I plan to send http request to the load balancer via enp0s3 interface on cp01 node.
do i need to :

- reset the cluster and do the kube init again using 0.0.0.0 ip or,
- is there a way to accomplish it without disturbing existing configurations/setup (using ingress?) ?

Please advice.
I have started learning kubernetes recently, so please excuse if i missed out on some basic concepts of the kubernetes world while framing these queries.
Please do let me know if something is unclear.

UPDATE:

Q2:
i tried initializing kubeadm node via -

```
[root@cp01 ~]# kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address 0.0.0.0  --pod-network-cidr 10.244.0.0/16 --cri-socket unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock
```

but with this method, worker nodes are unable to join cluster from 10.5.5.0/24 (enp0s8) network. they are able to join cluster as -

```
kubeadm join 192.168.29.73:6443 --cri-socket  unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock   --token 6srhn0.1lyiffiml08qcnfw --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:ab87e3e04da65176725776c08e0f924bbc07b26d0f8e2501793067e477ab6379
```

Answer (score 1):

Kubelet would usually bind to whichever interface holds your default gateway.
I suspect your SDN pods are failing to start up due to this. At that stage, I would check for `netstat`, `ip routes` and iptables rules.

You may want to remove the internal network thing. Deploying Kubernetes, it is recommended for your nodes to run in a LAN, using loadbalancers to expose your ingresses.

Otherwise, you need your default gateway to point to your internal network. And then, you'll need some kind of router, NAT-ing traffic while sending it back to your bridged network.